# git clone Could not resolve host: github.com while I can curl and wget from github.com

Tags: git, github, dns, ubuntu-18.04

I want to clone code from github on my unbuntu18.04, get error

```
git clone https://github.com/Ryan-Miao/docker-yapi.git
```

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://github.com/Ryan-Miao/docker-yapi.git/': Could not resolve
>   host: github.com

I can curl and wget from github.com, but cannot git clone

[image]

I can also  access GitHub in browser. So the dns mybe ok, but why git can not resolve.

**Why the wget and browser could reolve github.com but git clone doesn't?**

how to fix it? Do I need check my dns config?

Here is my dns config:

```
systemd-resolve --status
Global
     DNS Servers: 223.5.5.5
                  223.6.6.6
                  8.8.8.8
                  8.8.4.4
      DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                  16.172.in-addr.arpa
                  168.192.in-addr.arpa
                  17.172.in-addr.arpa
                  18.172.in-addr.arpa
                  19.172.in-addr.arpa
                  20.172.in-addr.arpa
                  21.172.in-addr.arpa
                  22.172.in-addr.arpa
                  23.172.in-addr.arpa
                  24.172.in-addr.arpa
                  25.172.in-addr.arpa
                  26.172.in-addr.arpa
                  27.172.in-addr.arpa
                  28.172.in-addr.arpa
                  29.172.in-addr.arpa
                  30.172.in-addr.arpa
                  31.172.in-addr.arpa
                  corp
                  d.f.ip6.arpa
                  home
                  internal
                  intranet
                  lan
                  local
                  private
                  test

    Link 5 (vethc4fc14b)
        Current Scopes: none
        LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
        DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no

    Link 3 (docker0)
        Current Scopes: none
        LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
        DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no

    Link 2 (enp4s0)
        Current Scopes: DNS
        LLMNR setting: yes
    MulticastDNS setting: no
        DNSSEC setting: no
        DNSSEC supported: no
            DNS Servers: 202.96.134.133
                        114.114.114.114
```

Comment: Weird it worked for me. Can you ping github.com from the command line?

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon See my question.  I can not ping github.com from the command line.

Comment: Your nameservers (DNS) are in /etc/resolv.conf. Google's primary DNS is 8.8.8.8 and secondary 4.4.4.4

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon  see my dns

```

Comment: Do you have problems only with that URL when you clone or do others work?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I only have problems when I try to using `git clone  xxxxx`, then the xxx host cannot resolved. But when I curl xxxx, it worked. I think maybe something wrong with the git package on Ubuntu, but I really known little about the principle of git.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried several approaches from stackoverflow and google with no success. And I opened a web browser with Mozilla engine in that case and downloaded a file when the situation occured with such message:
`Could not resolve host: github.com`

Answer (score 0):

I have try all the ways from stackoverflow and google, but nothing worked.

Finally, I create a docker containner to run git, it works.

So, there maybe something wrong on my ubuntu18.04 for git. Maybe the git package error for unbuntu.

Comment: I really do not think the problem is in the Ubuntu `git` package.